# Iterate through pandas dataframe and assign value from another dataframe based on matching conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign an aggregated value from one dataframe to a specific row in another dataframe based on multiple matching criteria. The first dataframe looks something like this:
[image: first dataframe]

and the second dataframe looks something like this:

[image: second dataframe]

For each row in the second dataframe, I want to assign a value to a new column which would be the sum of values in the first dataframe that 1) have the same name, 2) have a capturedate less than the cutoff date and 3) have a refunddate greater than the cutoff date.

Right now I am solving this by looping through the dataframe and assigning values to each row if those conditions are met, but I know I'm not supposed to be assigning values to a slice from a dataframe.

Thanks in advance for any help~

Comment: Please edit your post so that it doesn't contain images of text. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: It's rather difficult to copy/paste images for testing, and there's no way I'm going to re-type any of that by hand ~